# sscanf specifier %[] and buffer overflow

Tags: c, embedded, scanf

sorry for this "another" sscanf question but I cannot find any solution by experimenting.

Here is a string I want to parse and extract 2 substrings delimited by ":" :

```
char *str = "tag:R123:P1234";
```

This function does the job :

```
char r_value[5];
char p_value[6];
sscanf(str, "tag:%[^:]:%s", r_value, p_value);
// now r_value = "R123" and p_value = "P1234"
```

But now I want to be sure I will not overflow my receiving buffers:

```
sscanf(str, "tag:%[^:]:%5s", r_value, p_value);
// this is good for p_value, if I give something bigger than 5 character long it
// will be truncated, if less than 5 character long, I get it also
```

but problem is with the %[] format:

```
sscanf(str, "tag:%4[^:]:%5s", r_value, p_value);
// this will be ok if initial r_value is 4 char or less long
// but not OK if more than 4 char long, then it will be truncated,
// but p_value will not be found...
```

Please note I am in an embedded system; I cannot afford very large buffers to put higher the limit of the overflow...

Is there a way to solve my problem? Or should I do a manual loop on each character to do the parsing manually?

Comment: You don't want to ask about `sscanf`, don't use it. There are plenty of other ways to do things without it.

Comment: Try looking into the [`strtok()` function](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This task is much easier using `strtok_r`

```
char  r_value[5];
char  p_value[6];
char *token;
char *saveptr;

token = strtok_r(str, ":", &saveptr);
if (token == NULL)
    return; /* there is no ":" in the string so handle failure properly */
token = strtok_r(NULL, ":", &saveptr);
if (token == NULL)
    return; /* no more tokens found so handle failure properly */
strncpy(r_value, token, sizeof r_value);
r_value[sizeof(r_value) - 1] = '\0';
token = strtok_r(NULL, ":", &saveptr);
if (token == NULL)
    return; /* no more tokens found so handle failure properly */
strncpy(p_value, token, sizeof p_value);
p_value[sizeof(p_value) - 1] = '\0';
```

and you prevent overflowing your `r_value` and `p_value`.

The only extra thing is that you should copy `str` because `strtok_r` will need to modify it

```
char *str = "tag:R123:P1234";
```

change it to

```
char *str = strdup("tag:R123:P1234");
```

and remember to `free(str)` at the end.

Comment: great this is very good, and i can afford modifying the initial string so no need to save.

by the way how do you use sizeof without () in strncpy ?

Comment: `sizeof` is an operator not a function.

Comment: great 2 new thing to learn in 1 question ! thanks StackOverflow all of you ;)

Comment: @moquette31: The `sizeof` operator demands parentheses when the expression is a type and allows parentheses when it is an expression (such as a variable name).  Since parentheses are always correct (optional, but correct), I simply always write `sizeof(whatever)` and never need to remember the subtleties of when parentheses are mandatory and when they're optional.  Not everyone agrees with that attitude, but it makes coding simpler.

Answer (score 4):

One of the merits of [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html) is that if the first format string doesn't work as expected, you can try a second (and third, and …) format.  You don't readily get a second chance with the direct file I/O variants such as `scanf()` and `fscanf()`.

In this context, I would consider:

```
int n;
if ((n = sscanf(str, "tag:%4[^:]:%5s", r_value, p_value)) == 1)
    n = sscanf(str, "tag:%4[^:]%*[^:]:%5s", r_value, p_value);
if (n != 2)
    …report format error…
…continue with extra characters skipped…
```

The star `*` in `%*[^:]` suppresses the assignment of the scanned result, and the conversion specification is not counted in the return value from `sscanf()`.

If you need to know about the `p_value` being too long, you can use a `%n` conversion specification to check the offset (noting that `%n` is not counted in the return value from `sscanf()` and that no useful value will be in `o` unless `n == 2`):

```
int o;
int n;
if ((n = sscanf(str, "tag:%4[^:]:%5s%n", r_value, p_value, &o)) == 1)
    n = sscanf(str, "tag:%4[^:]%*[^:]:%5s%n", r_value, p_value, &o);
if (n != 2 || str[o] != '\0')
    …report format error…
…continue with extra characters skipped…
```

The `scanf()` functions in general, and `sscanf()` in particular, are powerful, flexible, and incredibly hard to use correctly.  Be cautious!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it with `sscanf`.  The first `sscanf` converts the R value while limiting to 4 characters. The second `sscanf` determines where the R value ends, without limiting the length, or storing the result. The third `sscanf` converts the P value, starting from the index determined by the second `sscanf`.

```
char *str = "tag:R123:P1234";
char r_value[5];
char p_value[6];

int success = 0;

if ( sscanf( str, "tag:%4[^:]", r_value ) == 1 )    // convert and store R value
{
    int n;
    sscanf( str, "tag:%*[^:]%n", &n );              // find the end of the R value

    if ( sscanf( &str[n], ":%5s", p_value ) == 1 )  // convert and store P value
        success = 1;
}

if ( success )
    printf( "%s\n%s\n", r_value, p_value );
```